# PHP mysqli help with binding var in code block?

Tags: php, mysqli, bind

I am pretty new to prepared statements, I am currently working through all my code to update it.

I need a bit of help rewriting the following code:

```
        if($stmt = $db->query("select * from product where active=1 and id=?")){
            echo "Returned Result";
        }else{
            echo "Invalid SQL";
        }
```

Using this code I need to bind the variable $_POST['id']:

```
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['id']);
```

where would I place the bind to get the whole code block to work?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `query()` you need to call `prepare()`:

```
// Prepare the statement first and bind params
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from product where active=1 and id=?")){
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['id']);

// Then execute it
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Returned Result";
    // Then fetch your results
} else {
    echo "Query failed";
}
```